# How to find whether a given IPv6 address falls in the CIDR range using C or C++?

Tags: c++, c, c++11

If I have an ipv6 address 2001:4860:4860:0000:0000:0000:012D:8888 and want to find whether this falls in the given CIDR range 2001:4860:4860:0000:0000:0000:0000:8888/32. How do I do this in C or C++?

I tried similarly as we do for ipv4. 
(ip & netmask) == (range & netmask)

```
unsigned int ipv6 = (ip[0]<<112) + (ip[1]<<96) + (ip[2]<<80) + (ip[3]<<64)+ (ip[4]<<48) + (ip[5]<<32) + (ip[6]<<16) + ip[7];

unsigned int range = (cidr_ip[0]<<112) + (cidr_ip[1]<<96) + (cidr_ip[2]<<80) + (cidr_ip[3]<<64)+ (cidr_ip[4]<<48) + (cidr_ip[5]<<32) + (cidr_ip[6]<<16) + cidr_ip[7];
unsigned int mask = (~0u) << (128-netmask);

if((ipv6 & mask) == (range & mask)){
    printf("matched\n");
}
else
{
    printf("no match\n");
}
```

This didn't work for me as expected. The above ipv6 falls in the range. But the program says "no match".

Comment: try https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__address_v6_range.html https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__basic_address_range_lt__address_v4__gt_.html

Comment: c and c++ are only related, one answer might not apply to both languages. Pick a language for the question.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that unsigned int usually only has a size of 32 Bits. Sometimes it's more, and sometimes it's less, but today there's no mainstream compiler for which it's 128 Bits. An IPv6 address needs 128 Bits.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

//Little struct containing a unsigned int array with the size of 4
//4 * 32bit = 128bit (== IPv6)
typedef struct IPv6_address{
    uint32_t ip_parts[4];
} IPv6;

IPv6 and(IPv6 first, IPv6 second);
short match(IPv6 first, IPv6 second);
IPv6 mask_from_prefix(int prefix);

int main(){
    int netmask = 32;
    unsigned int ip[8] = {0x2001, 0x4860, 0x4860, 0, 0, 0, 0x012D, 0x8888};
    unsigned int cidr_ip[8] = {0x2001, 0x4860, 0x4860, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x8888};

    IPv6 ipv6 = {(ip[0]<<16) + (ip[1]), (ip[2]<<16) + (ip[3]), (ip[4]<<16) + (ip[5]), (ip[6]<<16) + ip[7]};
    IPv6 range = {(cidr_ip[0]<<16) + (cidr_ip[1]), (cidr_ip[2]<<16) + (cidr_ip[3]), (cidr_ip[4]<<16) + (cidr_ip[5]), (cidr_ip[6]<<16) + cidr_ip[7]};
    IPv6 mask = mask_from_prefix(netmask);

    //if((ipv6 & mask) == (range & mask)){
    if(match(and(ipv6, mask), and(range, mask))){
        printf("matched\n");
    }
    else{
        printf("no match\n");
    }

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

//Bitwise-AND operation between two IPv6 addresses (128 bit integer as struct)
IPv6 and(IPv6 first, IPv6 second){
    IPv6 toReturn = {};
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        toReturn.ip_parts[i] = first.ip_parts[i] & second.ip_parts[i];
    }

    return toReturn;
}

//Returns 1, if the given IPv6 addresses match
//Otherwise 0
short match(IPv6 first, IPv6 second){
    short matchCount = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        if(first.ip_parts[i] == second.ip_parts[i]){
            matchCount++;
        }
    }

    return matchCount == 4 ? 1 : 0; //If all four parts match return 1, otherwise 0
}

//Returns an IPv6 address representing the net mask of the given prefix
IPv6 mask_from_prefix(int prefix){
    IPv6 mask = {};
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++){
        int onesForThisPart = prefix - i*32;

        //Check if 0 (or less), because shifting by 32 would result in an "erroneous" behavior, where nothing would happen at all
        if(onesForThisPart <= 0){
            mask.ip_parts[i] = 0;
        }
        else{
            mask.ip_parts[i] = (~0u) << (32 - onesForThisPart);
        }
    }

    return mask;
}
```

It's not the most beautiful solution, but it works.
Hope I could help!

Comment: You might consider replacing `unsigned int` with `uint32_t` (from stdint.h), just to make the 32-bits size of each ip_parts[] value more explicit.

Comment: Attempting to left-shift an operand by a number of bits greater than or equal to its width is undefined behavior. `ip[0]<<112`, etc., are bugs.

Comment: Next issue: endianness.

Comment: Yes this works. If the mask is 8 or 16, how can it be achieved?

Comment: _"unsigned int only has a size of 32 Bits"_ This is not necessarily true.

Comment: @Davislor endianness isn't a problem as long as you stay constant over the whole program. Personally I like it more this way, because it's more intuitive for me, but of course the order can be swapped.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Yes that's true, I assume that OP is using a compiler which defines unsigned int with 32 bits of size

Comment: @Moray It “isn’t a problem” until you recompile on another architecture and it breaks. Or worse, it doesn’t, and you realize you’ve been producing two incompatible data formats that now you have to support forever. A lot of companies have done this by accident.

Comment: @ChethanKT I have changed it now, so that you can generate a mask from a prefix.

Comment: @Davislor Oh you are right! Sorry I didn't think about that. I won't change it, because of time reasons, but +1 for your hint

Comment: @Moray Then I have made the correction for you. You should address the other issues when you have the time, because you would not want to spread misinformation.

Answer (score 1):

Boost ASIO's IP address and range classes do most of the work for this for you. Unfortunately they don't currently provide a way for parsing an IP address range from a string.

Most of the following code is the parser for an IP address range, the code works with both IP4 and IP6:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using namespace boost::asio::ip;

template < typename Addr >
bool parseAddress( const std::string& str, Addr& addr )
{
  boost::system::error_code ec;
  addr = Addr::from_string( str, ec );
  return !ec;
}

 address_v4_range getRange( address_v4 address, size_t size )
{
  address_v4 end = address_v4( ( address.to_ulong() + ( 1 << ( 32 - size ) ) ) & 0xFFFFFFFF );
  return address_v4_range( address, end );
}

address_v6_range getRange( address_v6 address, size_t size )
{
  auto bytes = address.to_bytes();
  size_t offset = size >> 3;
  uint8_t toAdd = 1 << ( 8 - ( size & 0x7 ) );
  while ( toAdd )
  {
    int value = bytes[ offset ] + toAdd;
    bytes[ offset ] = value & 0xFF;
    toAdd = value >> 8;
    if ( offset == 0 )
    {
      break;
    }
    offset--;
  }
  address_v6 end = address_v6( bytes );
  return address_v6_range( address, end );
} 

template < typename Addr >
bool parseRange( const std::string& str, basic_address_range< Addr >& range )
{
  size_t pos = str.find( '/' );
  if ( pos == std::string::npos )
  {
    return false;
  }
  // should only be one slash
  if ( str.find( '/', pos + 1 ) != std::string::npos )
  {
    return false;
  }
  boost::system::error_code ec;
  Addr address;
  if ( !parseAddress( str.substr( 0, pos ), address ) )
  {
    return false;
  }
  std::string sizeStr = str.substr( pos + 1 );
  size_t index;
  int size = std::stoi( sizeStr, &index );
  if ( index != sizeStr.size() )
  {
    return false;
  }
  if ( size > std::tuple_size< typename Addr::bytes_type >::value * 8 || size < 0 )
  {
    return false;
  }
  range = getRange( address, size );
  return !ec;
}

int main()
{
    address_v6 address;
    if ( !parseAddress( "2001:4860:4860:0000:0000:0000:012D:8888", address ) )
    {
        std::cout << "invalid address\n";
        return 1;
    }
    address_v6_range range;
    if ( !parseRange( "2001:4860:4860:0000:0000:0000:0000:8888/32", range ) )
    {
        std::cout << "invalid range\n";
        return 1;
    }
    bool inRange = range.find( address ) != range.end();
    std::cout << "in range: " << inRange << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have 128-bit unsigned int on your system (which you don't), you're well outside of range there. After that, your maths just don't work any more.

Use a nice IP library instead!

Answer (score 0):

It is simpler to treat IPv6 addresses as byte arrays rather than integer types as they are 128-bits and in network byte order.

```cpp
#include <algorithm> // std::equal
#include <cassert>   // assert

struct ipv6addr {
    unsigned char addr[16];

    bool is_subnet(const ipv6addr& prefix, unsigned int len) const {
        assert(len <= sizeof(addr) * 8);

        int cmp_bytes = len / 8;
        if (!std::equal(addr, addr + cmp_bytes, prefix.addr)) return false;

        int cmp_bits = len % 8;
        if (cmp_bits) {
            int bitmask = 0xff << (8 - cmp_bits);
            if ((addr[cmp_bytes] & bitmask) != (prefix.addr[cmp_bytes] & bitmask))
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
};

int main() {
    ipv6addr addr {0x20, 0x01, 0x48, 0x60, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x01, 0x2D, 0x88, 0x88};
    ipv6addr prefix {0x20, 0x01, 0x48, 0x60, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0x88, 0x88};
    unsigned int len = 32;

    assert(addr.is_subnet(prefix, len));

    return 0;
}
```

If you really want to store them as integers you can use something like `struct { uint64_t hi; uint64_t lo; }`, but you need to account for endianness while accessing/modifying those fields.

---

**Edit:** Came to think about it, I realized using memcmp for subnet comparison wasn't correct. I corrected the code above. Also I've replaced `memcmp` with`std::equal`, but either one is okay. I didn't extensively test it though, so you should definitely test it more if you decide to use it.